Creating a recursively nesting array structure from flat data in JavaScript
Looking for some help to build a deeply nested data structure in JavaScript.
I will have input data that takes the form like this:
      [
        ["World", "Asia", "Singapore", "Asia-Singapore", "1300"],
        ["World", "Asia", "India", "Asia-India", "850"],
        ["World", "Asia-Singapore", "Bond", "Bond-Singapore", "650"],
        ["World", "Asia-Singapore", "Bond", "Singapore-Bond", "650"],
        ["World", "Asia-China", "Bond", "Bond-China", "600"],
        ["World", "Asia-China", "Bond", "China-Bond", "600"],
        ["World", "Asia-India", "Equity", "Equity-India", "500"],
        ["World", "Asia-India", "Equity", "India-Equity", "500"],
        [
          "World",
          "Asia-China",
          "Private Equity",
          "China-Private Equity",
          "400",
        ],
        [
          "World",
          "Asia-China",
          "Private Equity",
          "Private Equity -China",
          "400",
        ],
        ["World", "Asia-India", "Bond", "Bond-India", "350"],
        ["World", "Asia-India", "Bond", "India-Bond", "350"],
        [
          "Jupiter",
          "Asia-Singapore",
          "Private Equity",
          "Private Equity -Singapore",
          "350",
        ],
        [
          "Jupiter",
          "Asia-Singapore",
          "Private Equity",
          "Singapore-Private Equity",
          "350",
        ],
        ["Jupiter", "Asia-Singapore", "Equity", "Equity-Singapore", "300"],
        ["Jupiter", "Asia-Singapore", "Equity", "Singapore-Equity", "300"],
        ["Jupiter", "Asia", "China", "Asia-China", "Franky", "290"],
        ["World", "Asia-China", "Equity", "China-Equity", "250"],
        ["World", "Asia-China", "Equity", "Equity-China", "250"],
        ["World", "Asia", "China", "Asia-China", "Billy", "110"],
        ["World", "Asia", "China", "Asia-China", "Freddy", "50"],
      ];

With an unpredictable number of columns in each row and I need to be able to create an output with the following structure (does not eactly match values from above, but required structure should be clear):
   const testData = [
      {
        name: "World",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Asia",
            children: [
              {
                name: "Asia-China",
                value: 110,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: "Jupiter",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Asia-Singapore",
            children: [
              {
                name: "Google",
                value: 200,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ];

So it will need to loop through each row though the flat array given (always with the 'Value' as the last item in the array that is the row, but not necessarily the same number of other values every time) and create groups for as many levels as there are, nesting child nodes and then putting the 'Value' value when there are no child nodes to add.
Hopefully someone can help me structure this up - I get all tied up in mental knots when it comes to anything recursive like this.
EDITS
Thanks to @Trushaba's input marked correct below. I've been able to work from their answer and solve this. For anyone facing a similar issue, the final code for the buildTree function is here:
     function buildTree(data) {
        const result = [];

        data.forEach((row) => {
          let currentLevel = result;
          row.slice(0, -1).forEach((name, index) => {
            let existing = currentLevel.find((item) => item.name === name);
            if (!existing) {
              if (name == row[row.length - 2]) {
                existing = {
                  name,
                  value: parseInt(row[row.length - 1]),
                };
              } else {
                existing = {
                  name,
                  children: [],
                };
              }
              currentLevel.push(existing);
            }

            if (existing.children) {
              currentLevel = existing.children;
            }
          });
        });
        return result;
      }


I know what the whole thing needs to do in principal, but failing to implement it in code - that's what I'm asking for help with.

I did specify in my post that the output is example only to illustrate the needed structure. Thanks for the feedback, though.

Yes, you did. Not sure why you created sample input and sample output that are totally unrelated. Stackoverflow is not a please write code for me site, but apparently, some people get away with it and have code written for them.

For this type of question, you need to show what code you've written to try to solve the problem yourself—even if it's bad or not working. Otherwise, it does seem like you've not attempted anything and are looking for someone to do work for you for free, which is generally ill-received on Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to show what you've attempted so far, and include that in future questions.

I like to think of this sort of problem as a series of simpler steps.  And I prefer to build general reusable tools to perform these steps.  So in the end, the code ends up a simple call to those steps.  Here I would go through two intermediate formats on my way to the final version.
First I would convert the input to this format:
[
    [["World", "Asia", "Singapore", "Asia-Singapore"], "1300"],
    [["World", "Asia", "India", "Asia-India"], "850"],
    // ...
    [["World", "Asia", "China", "Asia-China", "Freddy"], "50"]
]

That is, I would separate out the path parts from the final values.
Then, using one of my favorite utility functions, hydrate, I would convert that to:
{
    World: {
        Asia: {
            Singapore: {"Asia-Singapore": "1300"},
            India: {"Asia-India": "850"},
            China: {"Asia-China": {Billy: "110", Freddy: "50"}}
        },
        "Asia-Singapore": {
            Bond: {"Bond-Singapore": "650", "Singapore-Bond": "650"}
        },
        // ...
    },
    Jupiter: {
        // ...
    }
}

For my own use-cases, this format is usually the correct one, but you wanted something slightly different. It turns out quite simple to convert between the above and this format:
[
    {
        name: "World",
        children: [{
            name: "Asia",
            children: [{
                name: "Singapore", 
                children: [{name: "Asia-Singapore", value: "1300"}]
            }, {
                name: "India",
                children: [{name: "Asia-India", value: "850"}]
            }, {
                name: "China",
                children: [{
                    name: "Asia-China",
                    children: [
                        {name: "Billy", value: "110"},
                        {name: "Freddy", value: "50"}
                    ]
                }]
            }]
        },
        // ...
    },
    {
       name: "Jupiter"
       children: [ /* ... */ ]
    }
]

To do that, I use this code:


const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object.assign (
    Array.isArray (o) || Number.isInteger(p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: setPath(ps)(v)((o || {})[p])}
  )

const hydrate = (xs) =>
  xs.reduce((a, [p, v]) => setPath(p)(v)(a), {})

const toTree = (o) => Object.entries(o).map(
  ([k, v]) => Object(v) === v ? {name: k, children: toTree(v)} : {name: k, value: v}
)

const deepNest = (xss) =>
  toTree(hydrate(xss.map(xs => [xs.slice(0, -1), xs.at(-1)])))

const input = [["World", "Asia", "Singapore", "Asia-Singapore", "1300"], ["World", "Asia", "India", "Asia-India", "850"], ["World", "Asia-Singapore", "Bond", "Bond-Singapore", "650"], ["World", "Asia-Singapore", "Bond", "Singapore-Bond", "650"], ["World", "Asia-China", "Bond", "Bond-China", "600"], ["World", "Asia-China", "Bond", "China-Bond", "600"], ["World", "Asia-India", "Equity", "Equity-India", "500"], ["World", "Asia-India", "Equity", "India-Equity", "500"], ["World", "Asia-China", "Private Equity", "China-Private Equity", "400"], ["World", "Asia-China", "Private Equity", "Private Equity -China", "400"], ["World", "Asia-India", "Bond", "Bond-India", "350"], ["World", "Asia-India", "Bond", "India-Bond", "350"], ["Jupiter", "Asia-Singapore", "Private Equity", "Private Equity -Singapore", "350"], ["Jupiter", "Asia-Singapore", "Private Equity", "Singapore-Private Equity", "350"], ["Jupiter", "Asia-Singapore", "Equity", "Equity-Singapore", "300"], ["Jupiter", "Asia-Singapore", "Equity", "Singapore-Equity", "300"], ["Jupiter", "Asia", "China", "Asia-China", "Franky", "290"], ["World", "Asia-China", "Equity", "China-Equity", "250"], ["World", "Asia-China", "Equity", "Equity-China", "250"], ["World", "Asia", "China", "Asia-China", "Billy", "110"], ["World", "Asia", "China", "Asia-China", "Freddy", "50"]]


console.log(deepNest(input))
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}



Our three steps are:

xss.map(xs => [xs.slice(0, -1), xs.at(-1)]), which splits each of our input arrays into two: (a) the last node, and (b) all those before it, which form the path to the value in our final object
hydrate, which in turns depends upon setPath.  setPath is the only somewhat tricky function here.  It takes a path, a value, and an object, and sets the value to the node at the end of the path, reusing or creating the intermediate nodes along the way.  hydrate simply folds multiple path-entry pairs into a single object by reducing our list of path entries using setPath.
toTree, which I wrote only for this, but which I will add to my utility library once I find a better name for it.  It takes an object structure and turns it into nested object of {name, value} or {name, children:[]} pairs.


This is a wonderful, detailed and educational answer, @Scott. Thank you for spending the time to document this

I'm still not totally content with the auto-switching of [] and {}. In both our solutions, certain inputs can cause unexpected outputs. For example, when o is an array and p is non-numeric, this code will set a string property on an array. Or if o is an object but p is numeric, it will recast the object as an array.  You can break mine in a similar way. I think these cases should result in errors. It's not a tough fix, but feels beyond the scope a post here. Especially without pattern matching to keep it concise..

@Mulan, I feel as though that's just a matter of GIGO.  I simply want to be able to ensure I can capture the data structure through such lists of path entries.  I don't feel that every possible list of path entries has to have a logical result.  Even simpler than object/array, what would we expect to get back from [[['foo'], 1], [['foo'], 2]]?  Does the first one win?  Does the last one win?  Do we error?  As a matter of API, I'm willing to punt on that and let it fall out of the implementation.

You could use Array.reduceRight and populate the output data like so. It iterates from the inner most level and deal with the last two elements exceptionally, then populate the outer structures layer by layer.


const input = [
  ["World", "Asia", "Singapore", "Asia-Singapore", "1300"],
  ["World", "Asia", "India", "Asia-India", "850"],
  ["Jupiter", "Asia-Singapore", "Private Equity", "Private Equity -Singapore", "350"]
];

const output = input.map(arr => arr.reduceRight((acc, name, i, arr) => {
  if (i >= arr.length - 2) {
    return { name, value: +acc };
  }

  return { name, children: [acc] };
}));

console.log(output);




Thank you for this answer - the succint code is fantastic - it only lacks the grouping needed. So with your sample data, the output still has two records called 'World' rather than grouping these

I see, but in the required structure you didn't mention that though.

Recursive get and set are adapted from my post in this Q&A. You can see other approaches in that thread. Note some complexity in set can be removed if support for arrays is not required -


const get = (t, path) =>
  path.reduce((r, k) => r?.[k], t)

const set = (t, path) => {
  // invariant:
  if (path.length < 1)
    throw Error("path must contain at least one value")

  // base case: path has one element, the value
  if (path.length == 1)
    return path[0]

  // inductive: path has two elements, or more
  const k = path[0]

  // invariant:
  if (t != null && typeof t != "object")
    throw Error(`cannot set property ${k} of ${typeof t}`)

  // recur
  return Object.assign(
    t ?? (typeof k == "number" ? [] : {}), // optional: array support
    { [k]: set(t?.[k], path.slice(1)) },
  )
}

const fromPaths = paths =>
  paths.reduce(set, {})
  
const mytree = fromPaths([
  ["World", "Asia", "Singapore", "Asia-Singapore", "1300"],
  ["World", "Asia", "India", "Asia-India", "850"],
  ["World", "Asia-Singapore", "Bond", "Bond-Singapore", "650"],
  ["World", "Asia-Singapore", "Bond", "Singapore-Bond", "650"],
  ["World", "Asia-China", "Bond", "Bond-China", "600"],
  ["World", "Asia-China", "Bond", "China-Bond", "600"],
  ["World", "Asia-India", "Equity", "Equity-India", "500"],
  ["World", "Asia-India", "Equity", "India-Equity", "500"],
  [
    "World",
    "Asia-China",
    "Private Equity",
    "China-Private Equity",
    "400",
  ],
  [
    "World",
    "Asia-China",
    "Private Equity",
    "Private Equity -China",
    "400",
  ],
  ["World", "Asia-India", "Bond", "Bond-India", "350"],
  ["World", "Asia-India", "Bond", "India-Bond", "350"],
  [
    "Jupiter",
    "Asia-Singapore",
    "Private Equity",
    "Private Equity -Singapore",
    "350",
  ],
  [
    "Jupiter",
    "Asia-Singapore",
    "Private Equity",
    "Singapore-Private Equity",
    "350",
  ],
  ["Jupiter", "Asia-Singapore", "Equity", "Equity-Singapore", "300"],
  ["Jupiter", "Asia-Singapore", "Equity", "Singapore-Equity", "300"],
  ["Jupiter", "Asia", "China", "Asia-China", "Franky", "290"],
  ["World", "Asia-China", "Equity", "China-Equity", "250"],
  ["World", "Asia-China", "Equity", "Equity-China", "250"],
  ["World", "Asia", "China", "Asia-China", "Billy", "110"],
  ["World", "Asia", "China", "Asia-China", "Freddy", "50"],
])

console.log(JSON.stringify(mytree, null, 2))
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }



Output
{
  "World": {
    "Asia": {
      "Singapore": {
        "Asia-Singapore": "1300"
      },
      "India": {
        "Asia-India": "850"
      },
      "China": {
        "Asia-China": {
          "Billy": "110",
          "Freddy": "50"
        }
      }
    },
    "Asia-Singapore": {
      "Bond": {
        "Bond-Singapore": "650",
        "Singapore-Bond": "650"
      }
    },
    "Asia-China": {
      "Bond": {
        "Bond-China": "600",
        "China-Bond": "600"
      },
      "Private Equity": {
        "China-Private Equity": "400",
        "Private Equity -China": "400"
      },
      "Equity": {
        "China-Equity": "250",
        "Equity-China": "250"
      }
    },
    "Asia-India": {
      "Equity": {
        "Equity-India": "500",
        "India-Equity": "500"
      },
      "Bond": {
        "Bond-India": "350",
        "India-Bond": "350"
      }
    }
  },
  "Jupiter": {
    "Asia-Singapore": {
      "Private Equity": {
        "Private Equity -Singapore": "350",
        "Singapore-Private Equity": "350"
      },
      "Equity": {
        "Equity-Singapore": "300",
        "Singapore-Equity": "300"
      }
    },
    "Asia": {
      "China": {
        "Asia-China": {
          "Franky": "290"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Nice functions as always, but: First, take a look again at the requested output, with its name/children format.  My answer converts from the simple object structure to the requested format as a last step, since I agree that the intermediate format is cleaner.  Second, is this how you would choose to structure the input, or would you prefer (as I do) to separate the path from the value to be set?  My version converts the input to my preferred format, translates that to a simple output, then does another step to get the requested format: perhaps overkill, but then has reusable functions.


Oops, I completely missed that part of it. The suggested data structure does not make sense for the presented hierarchical data, imo. Named-based categories, which can be easily represented with object keys, are traded for arbitrary numerical indexes in children arrays. This makes common tree operations like insertion or lookup difficult to write. Performance will be poor unless corresponding numerical indexes are known ahead of time.



I don't have a strong opinion on it as it's easy to convert one to the other. I chose to work with the input as-is, sometimes this is a natural way to express the tree, and reduces one level of nesting.


I'm just philosophically bothered by an array of [String, String, String, ...., String, Arbitrary].  But you're right, it's not that big a deal.

In a typed setting, I'd be bothered too, yikes
